# Reducing subspaces of a normal operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

If $A$ is a normal operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$, then $H$ is the direct sum of a countably infinite collection of subspaces that reduce $A$, all with the same infinite dimensional.

For this problem I thought about compact normal operator, In this case I can write $H$  as a countable directed sum of **finite** dimensional reducing subspace. Is it correct? while the question  supposed to be a directed sum of infinite dimensional subspaces. So because of it I get confused.

I do not have any idea about it. Please help me about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "reduce" here?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom :  There is not any specific definition for it in my text book. The aim of this question shows one way to say that the spectral theorem provides many reducing subspaces and using spectral theorem we can reduce the study of a normal operator to subspaces with various desirable properties.

Comment: Are you allowed to take the full spectral theorem as for unbounded normal operators as granted?

Comment: Reduce usually means: $N(Z\cap\mathcal{D}N)\subseteq Z$, $N(Z^\perp\cap\mathcal{D}N)\subseteq Z^\perp$

Comment: @Freeze_S: I just know spectral theorem for bounded operators

Comment: Bounded normal operators I guess like from C*-algebraic approach?

Comment: For more aspects on reducing spaces regarding its definition you may have at: [Reducing](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A79762+reducing+subspaces)

Comment: @Freeze_S: For this problem I thought about compact normal operator, In this case I can write $H$ as a countable directed sum of  finite dimensional reducing subspace. Is it correct? So because of it I get confused.

Comment: Yep correct. Now for normal not necessarily compact operators?

Comment: @Freeze_S: but the question supposed to be a directed sum of infinite dimensional subspaces.

Comment: Oui nice question... puuh..